# Apache Beam Runner for a single machine in Production

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

From what I've read from Apache Beam's documentation, the Direct Runner should be used as a runner to test/debug your pipeline code.

Thing is, my use-case consists of big and (sometimes) small datasets that should be processed in batches. I want to reuse the same pipeline code for both types of datasets.

I don't think paralellism would be beneficial for writing small datasets (2000/3000 records) in a SQL database most of the times. If I were to use Cloud Dataflow with small datasets, I would have an overhead related to VM startup time, since it isn't possible to use a single dedicated VM in Dataflow.

In this context, I thought of using the Direct Runner to deal with the small datasets. Would this be a bad decision on a production environment? Or is there a runner more suitable for this that I don't know about?

Also, does Direct Runner creates threads for ParDo transforms automatically? If yes, is there an argument/option to specify the maximum number of threads the runner should work with?

Comment: From my experience Direct Runner consumes much more resources and is slower than Dataflow Runner. It's probably OK for small datastets. But also with a Direct Runner you would miss Dataflow UI graph representation and built-in logging.

Kind of another approach could be to modify pipeline to run into streaming mode.
This way you can run it on a single dedicated VM with Dataflow and avoid startup time. I think the complexity of pipeline modification to streaming mode highly depends on data source you are using.

Comment: "...since it isn't possible to use a single dedicated VM in Dataflow"

Why isn't it possible? Simply use `--max_num_workers=1` and you'll have just one VM for your DataFlow job